# Phonegap/Cordova build onResume event not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I'm using Phonegap Build to create an app and I'm simply loading a whole webpage in the webview.

The problem is that the onResume and onPause event is not firing if I load the webpage, if I don´t load the page then it is firing as it should.

I use this.

```
function onBodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {

    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

    setTimeout(function () {    
        //if I don´t use this, then the events are working, 
        //but as soon as I load the page the events are not firing?
        document.location.href = "http://somepage.se/";

    }, 0);

}
```

So why is the event working if I don´t load the webpage?

---

SOLVED! My mistake, when I load with window.load then it replaces my hole page, so therefor it never fires the event since it is gone. So I have to use jQuery to load it in a div instead, then it loads the page inside the existing one, it is not replacing it.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the problem you have, and I can tell you that this is not the problem which you actually have.

`onPause` event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically **when the user switches** to another application.

`OnResume` event fires when an application is **retrieved** from the background.

For full docs, read [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)!

Comment: proofzy, thanks, yes I know that. But why is both of them work if I don´t use document.load.href? If I don´t load the page, and closes the app and then open it it is firing onResume, and if I do the same when I load the page it is not firing onResume.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson It should work.. Maybe your onPause event not working, so then app can't resume. Try this full example [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause). And also controle it with alert or console.log

Comment: My misstake, when I load with window.load then it replaces my hole page. So I have to use jQuery to load it in a div instead. Thanks.